# Like button and comments from a friend's post/link

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm writing an app for Facebook which browses through shared links that friends have posted.

My goal is, that I dynamically load information from a link that has been shared by a friend.  This part is easy and already done.  Now I would like to load the comments of that post and the option to like that friend's post.  This however, is a mystery on how to solve...

I tried to use the 'Like button plugin', but this likes the link to the post of the link.  Not the post. Everything I could have come up with for the URL parameter made me like the URL not the post behind it.

I can use FQL to like the post using /post_id/likes via POST request, but then I'd would have to create the button from scratch, which may be doable for the like button, but not the whole comments plugin.

Comment: Ok I found that if I use the button for my own posts (e.g., URL = http://www.facebook.com/roy.wichhart/posts/3282376832308), the Like button works.  If I try to like a firend's post, no go...

Comment: I've filed a bug report to Facebook. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/502608973087012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Facebook, this is by design:
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/502608973087012

A work around is using the Graph API:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/#likes

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly. You can set the target url of the like button.
One way to do so is:

```
<fb:like href="the target website"></fb:like>
```

according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

> href - the URL to like. The XFBML version defaults to the current
>   page.

Comment: Setting the target URL for the like button only likens the URL of the post, not the post itself. I also don't get to see other ppl's likes either of that post. Perhaps I should create screenshots?

Comment: do you mean like box? like box can set the href attribute too. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Comment: Woops didn't see your comment. No, although the like box has the same problem. What I'm trying to do is liking an object on facebook. I have the object_id, if I go to http://www.facebook.com/obect_id, I get the object, but when I enter that url in HREF, and click Like, it shows on my timeline as I liked the URL "http://www.facebook.com/object_id", not the object itself... It only shows the URL on my timeline, it doesn't show any metadata...